# Receiving distinct models based on nested clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am looking for the best, built in mechanism to receive distinct models based on a nested where clause.

With this example, I receive the models but they are not unique.

```
QuestionPage
  .joins(:industry_questions)
  .where(:industry_questions => {:tag => industry})
```

If I use the distinct keyword such as in the example below, I receive the correct result; but as a hash.

```
QuestionPage
      .distinct
      .joins(:industry_questions)
      .where(:industry_questions => {:tag => industry})
```

I know I can use .uniq in code to get the distinct QuestionPage models but is there a better way? Preferably without using string literals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out, you have to use references and includes like this.

```
QuestionPage
    .includes(:industry_questions)
    .references(:industry_questions)
    .where(:industry_questions => {:tag => industry})
```